# Twig with two loops (non-symfony)

Tags: php, twig

Still new to `twig` here and i'm kind of confused about a nested foreach and how to implement it into `twig`. I got an example code for timezones in php here:

```
foreach($timezones as $region => $list)
{
  print '<optgroup label="' . $region . '">' . "\n";
  foreach($list as $timezone => $name)
  {
    print '<option name="' . $timezone . '">' . $name . '</option>' . "\n";
  }
  print '<optgroup>' . "\n";
}
```

I know how to use the for tag for a simple array but that's all i know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the for tags with the and [Iterate over Keys and Values](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values).

The translation of your function is:

```
{% for region, list in timezones %}
    <optgroup label={{region}}>
        {% for timezone, name in list %}
            <option name="{{timezone }}">{{name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    <optgroup>
{% endfor %}
```

Se a running sample on this [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/u8f1ma)

Hope this help